# Out-file not writing errors, only successes

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I've got the following piece of code that runs a separate powershell script, passing some arguments as necessary.

```
& $UpdateAppConfig -webConfigPath $AppConfig -keyName SQLServer -keyValue $SQLServer | out-file $PSLogFile -append -Encoding Ascii
```

However, it isn't pushing out errors that may occur, just the successful output. Am I missing something from my out-file piping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Out-File` does not redirect errors, only standard output. It essentially is an alias for the redirector `>`. In its place you could use `Start-Transcript`/`Stop-Transcript` which captures all data to file.

```
Start-Transcript -Path $PSLogFile
& $UpdateAppConfig -webConfigPath $AppConfig -keyName SQLServer -keyValue $SQLServer 
Stop-Transcript
```

Sure there is another answer about this but havent found it yet. You should also be able to do

```
& $UpdateAppConfig -webConfigPath $AppConfig -keyName SQLServer -keyValue $SQLServer *>> $PSLogFile
```

`*>>` Would append *all* output to file. See more information from [about_Redirectors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx)
Have to check if that actually would work.